# matrix reallocation

Tags: matlab, matrix, memory-management

I'm trying to squeeze execution time on a script avoiding useless big-matrix reallocation.
An operation like

```
B = A;
```

causes little overhead since `B` will point at the same structure of `A`, and Matlab won't allocate a new one until an update occurs.

But what about an operation like this?

```
longVector = longVector(1:n);
```

Will it simply update `longVector` structure to point to the already existing subset of datas or (more time expensive) will it cause to allocate a new vector and trash the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will shrink the allocated block, but it will lead to fragmentation (on a Windows system) over time.

Comment: well, I run some rough profiling... `clear all; clc; tic A = ones(1,100000); toc tic A = A(1:50000); toc tic B = ones(1,50000); toc tic B=A; toc`. `A` resizing takes about the same time of `B` allocation (so it looks like isn't just re-referencing the old segment), while the last assignement time has a far smaller magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be better necessarily (I haven't tested the difference), but you could instead try `longVector(n+1:end)=[]`. I'm pretty sure that won't allocate a new variable.

Comment: looks like this way takes way more time than `longVector` initialization itself

Comment: Make sure to do all your timings with the code you're timing inside a function, otherwise many optimisations won't get applied. Try using Steve Eddins' `timeit` function from the MATLAB Central File Exchange, which takes care of a lot of subtleties for you, such as warming the code up by running it a few times. Having said that - I'm not implying you'll get different results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in MATLAB

```
A = B;
```

unless followed by

```
clear B;
```

uses up at least twice the memory.
At least on mac and up to a few versions back (2009 or so) it was so.

By the way it is not clear what you are trying to achieve here?
Why this would improve your performance?